# Webserver in C++, how to send an image

Tags: c++, linux, image, webserver

I am making my own simple webserver and I have gotten text files and html files to send perfectly, but when I try to send images, I am having some issues, and I can't figure it out.

Here is what I have.  I know sending one byte at a time is inefficient but it was for testing.

```
char buffer[1];
send_header(new_fd, get_file_type(file_location));
ifstream file;
file.open(temp.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
while (file.good())
{
    file.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
 send(new_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
}
```

Any ideas?  Do I need to convert it to network byte order before I send?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you are going to stick with this approach, you should define buffer to be something like 4096 bytes.  Using a 1-byte buffer will result in tons more system calls, which will slow down the server dramatically.

Comment: If you really want to be hard-core, you could mmap() the file manually, and then writev() both the header and the file at the same time. BSD's sendfile() does this for you; Linux's is rather limited, so you'll have to call mmap()/writev() yourself.

Comment: @cdhowie, lol I know I was using it to test some stuff, I switched it to 1024, because it wasn't even working correct with your solution with it set to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strlen(buffer)` is going to count up to the first null character (`'\0'`), which is a very common byte in image data.  You need to, instead, figure out how many bytes were actually read (`ifstream.read()` does not supply this information) and use that in place of your `strlen` call.

**EDIT:** You can obtain this with `ifstream.gcount()` -- so just replace your `strlen` call with `file.gcount()` and everything should magically work.

Answer (score 6):

@cdhowie is right about `strlen()` as the culprit. However, if you really want to be "modern" consider using `sendfile()`. It will `mmap()` the file you want to send for you.

Using `sendfile()` will prevent you from reading the file into temporary memory only to send it out to some other recipient. It not only saves steps, but also causes fewer page faults for really big files (such as images).

Comment: Cool, I'm always down to be modern I'll check it out.

Comment: I would definitely consider going this route as well.  Read/write sending mechanisms should really only be used when you need to process the stream (e.g. compression/encryption).

Comment: Or in case someone else whats to do something similar in windows the equivalent is called TransmitFile.